# Updating grub configuration is only working from the last installed system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Installing more than one ubuntu systems only let me use the very last to update grub configuration.

Configure the grub to my needs then execute `sudo update-grub` will work on any system but only is recognized when doing so from the **last installed system**. Otherwise has no effect even if the upgrade-grub command was successfully finished before.

This behavior was different in former times say around with 14.04./16.04.
At that time when using a custom menu on a multiboot system with the first entry made form `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` I could do that from any system not only from the last one (it takes effect from the system where I updated grub, so the first menu entry loads this system).

Can anyone confirm that "new" behavior and what is a good solution?
Or what I'm doing wrong?

THX for any good advise!

Comment: While I can't provide a working solution, I can confirm the behavior. I recently came across [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617045/how-do-i-install-two-independent-ubuntu-installations-on-a-single-hard-drive-wit), but haven't had the opportunity to fully try them out. In the past, I have tried the steps outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161072/1318896) (also mentioned in the linked thread), but without success.

Comment: Thx for confirming this behavior. Is this a bug or now a wanted behavior?

Comment: From my understanding, I think it's more of a bug with how grub is managing the EFI configuration. It looks like there is only one \EFI\ubuntu for multiple installs. The instance of Ubuntu that boots depends on whichever one wrote to it last with ```update-grub```.